# How can I prevent a website from disabling form autocompletion?

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, passwords

UBS is now using the autoComplete OFF for their login form to prevent passwords from being filled in automatically. From my perspective, this is actually just a nuisance. I don't need UBS to manage my security for me.

It's being done in one of the scripts that is loaded when you access their main client site.

So my question is whether there might be a way to prevent a site from disabling autocompletion? Could this be done with GreeceMonkey somehow?

Thanks,
D
P.S. To save getting lectured on the importance of security, let me add that I'm using WholeDisk Encryption so my machine can't even be booted up without a password.

Comment: you can have the fort knox anti-everything in your computer, but if you let the browser store the passwords, it's as simple as you going to the bathroom, and someone coming in, go to 'options->security->saved passwords' and seeing all your stored passwords. Just sayin'

Comment: Really? Was I wasting my time to ask not to be lectured on security?

This is a computer in my home office --- there is no "someone" to come in. Sigh!

Answer (score 2):

Type the following into the URL bar (in a single line) or make it a bookmarklet

```
javascript: function turnOnAutoComplete(tagName) {
                var els = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
                for (var i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
                    els[i].removeAttribute("autocomplete");
                }
            }
            turnOnAutoComplete('input');
            turnOnAutoComplete('form');
```

For an example, go to http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_AUTOCOMPLETE.html The input field on that page is set to autocomplete="OFF", so you get no autocomplete for that field.

Then you can go and run the script above from the URL bar and you should see that will now get autocomplete suggestions, unless you've never filled out a form with a name.

Comment: Wouldn't the autocomplete being off already stop the browser from filling the input field prior to the bookmarlet being executed?

Comment: @j08691 Try it out. Not having the autocomplete attribute means it will have its default behavior, which is to autocomplete

Comment: This looks interesting but I don't quite understand how the ordering would work. The javascript that disables autocompletion is pulled in when I load the UBS main page. Surely I can't run this first since there won't be a document and running it afterwards won't work because the javascript that disables autocompletion will have already run. (I tried that by the way)

Comment: @David  It's not JavaScript that prevents the autocompletion, it's HTML. There may be some crazy hack in UBS's page. Why don't you post a link to the page you're talking about

Comment: Well, if you go to https://onlineservices.ubs.com/olsauth/ex/pbl/ubso/dl and take a look at the second javascript file that is referenced  (https://onlineservices.ubs.com/olsauth/public/common/js/device.js), there is a function called checkCookieExists and one of the things it does early is turn off AutoComplete for the form.

Comment: @David: I honestly don't understand what you're confused about. You found the code that turns off autocomplete. If you run the script I showed you it will undo what the website did, that is it will remove the autocomplete attribute.

Comment: Well, why don't you try logging in yourself and saving the username/password? It doesn't matter if you use invalid stuff, you should still get prompted again. I think they've also managed to prevent the browser from remembering the entries as well since one doesn't even get prompted about remembering them.

Comment: I know you can't sign up without a username and account but if you type in anything, your browser should still prompt you to save the values.

Comment: This is a pretty late comment, but I can confirm that David was right: the script does not work.